# SSIS OLEDB Source (that uses ODBC Connection) Fails with Connection Failure Error

Tags: ms-access, ssis, odbc, sql-server-2017

Hello Fellow Programmers,

I have got myself in bit of a messy situation and wondered if anyone has any idea on how I can sort this out.

I have a System that uses GuptaSQL as their Backend. We normally use MS Access (.mdb File) to connect to GuptaSQL tables using the local ODBC Connection (From External Data -> ODBC Database) and Query all the tables as Linked Tables within Access. I have now created some views with simple SELECT * statements to get these tables in SQL as Linked Tables do not appear as available objects when you try to import these tables via SSIS.

Views are working fine when I open them in the MS Access Database, views are also appearing in the available Source in my SSIS Package's OLE DB Source. I can even see columns from view and Map them with the destination SQL table within SSIS.

However, when I run the Package, I get an error message saying "ODBC Connection to 'ODBC Connection Name' failed. (Microsoft Access Database Engine)"

Any Idea how I can resolve this? or any alternative to load this data into SQL?

Kind Regards,
Maulin.

Comment: As far as I remember, ODBC connection is a little bit of a pain in the neck with SSIS, you need to register it in local odbc drivers and etc. Search in this direction.

Comment: OLE DB <> ODBC. Use the `ODBC Source` instead of the `OLE DB Source`.